# Options for Header and Footer in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

This is not particularly related to programming, but I am confused and a beginner too so asking here. I am implementing the screen shown below. Clearly, It shows that it can be implemented by using a UITableView with `header(Invoice|Date|Vale|Action)` and `footer(Total)`.Please ignore the navigation bar. Since, header and footer are just informative with no user interaction, I want to use `UILabel` as an alternative of header and footer. What I did is attached label in ViewController and between that label added an `UITableview`. Its working fine on simulator, doesn't have device to test it on.

1)Is this a right way?

2)If it is right, would it show some strange behaviour on device?

3)This approach is okay for `autolayout`?

[image: This is to be implemented]

Comment: This seems like it *could* look odd on a different sized device. How are you determining the spacing of the information in the `TableViewCell`? If each of the items are set to have equal widths, then it should be okay.

Comment: yes, In cell prototyping I'll give the label items equal width and textAlignment from right. Would it work on all device?

Comment: Just thinking about this approach, cause it looks more easier and simple then the default one.

Comment: As long as they are set to be equal on both `TableViewCell` and the label items, it will be fine. @VijaySanghavi has a good answer as well.

Comment: Actually, only use @VijaySanghavi's suggestion if you do not need for the header to *act* like a header. In this case, the header would no longer be static.

Comment: okay, thanks for your suggestion i am going to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it in right way, but if you use `UITableViewCell` for header labels than you can do it more easily. It just like label of your `UITableViewCell` and header are of equal width so  for `indexPath.row == 0` you can set label colors and the label title and for remaining indexes you can do your work as you shown in image.

For footer using label is good approach.

EDIT: If the header labels are static then put them in the table header content view so they won't scroll with other cells.

Comment: This answer is good although the header would now be a cell so it would get lost as the user scrolls down the table.

Comment: Only catch is that, in my case both header and footer are static. It would be shown to the user, during scrolling.

Comment: Yeah that's right, but if we do not want to scroll that `UITableViewCell` than we can put that cell in `contentView` of header.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing right.I think the total invoice footer is a separate out tableview so user can always see it. If you have a lot data, user have scroll too much to see total. And with header you should make good constraints avoid strange layout when you show in real device (4,5 vs 6, 6plus)

Comment: As suggested by @Vijay Sanghavi, we can use label Instead of another TableView. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

To add header view and footer view in `UITableView` you can use:

```
tableViewObj.tableFooterView = footerViewObj;
tableViewObj.tableHeaderView = headerViewObj;
```

Comment: I know how to add header and footer, my question is little different.